# Remove prefix from NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, macos, cocoa, nsstring

How can I delete the prefix "test" from a NSString?
I've tried `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` but it's not what I want because it's the prefix that I want to remove not from the other occurrences of the string.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
NSString *prefixToRemove = @"test";
NSString *newString = [originalString copy];
if ([originalString hasPrefix:prefixToRemove])
    newString = [originalString substringFromIndex:[prefixToRemove length]];
```

Comment: And for those who would like to remove the suffix, you can try that:
newString = [originalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, originalString.length-suffix.length)]

Comment: @darksider because of people like you... I open unrelated questions too to find the solution... thanks

Comment: Why do you make a `copy` of `originalString`?

Comment: @meaning-matters Because if the string doesn't have the specified prefix, you want the new string to be the same as the original string. You could of course move that copy into an else branch instead.